Flutter - Cupertino Page Router gesture issue
I am using different navigation for different platforms using a static function. The default pop gesture of iOS is working, but in some screens can't pop using the gesture.
here is the router handling class,
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EnterExitRouteFactory {
  static PageRoute createRoute(
      {required Widget enterPage, required Widget exitPage}) {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => enterPage);
    } else {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => enterPage,
      );
    }
  }
}


push navigating code is,

Navigator.push(
      context,
      EnterExitRouteFactory.createRoute(
        exitPage: Container(),
        enterPage: Profil(widget.userId, avatar),
      ),
    );


I am using willpop in such screens that the gesture doesn't work. Does that affect pop gesture?
nb: 'exitPage' parameter is passed to use animations before.
I was trying to show different route animation for different Platforms(iOS, android). First i was used animations transitions, then used default route widgets. then I faced some issues.
